# Computing directional derivative of $f(x,y,z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the direction derivative of $f(x,y,z) = xy + yz + xz$ at the point $P(1,1,1)$ in the direction of $v = \langle7,3,-6\rangle$. I got the answer as $32/\sqrt{94}$. Is that right? If not what is the right answer please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left . f_v \right |_P = \left . \left ( \nabla f\cdot \frac v{|v|} \right )\right |_P = \left . \left ( \frac {\langle y + z, x + z, x + y\rangle \cdot \langle 7, 3, -6\rangle}{\sqrt{49+9+36}} \right ) \right |_P = \left . \left ( \frac {-3x+y+10z}{\sqrt{94}}\right ) \right |_P = \frac 8{\sqrt{94}}
$$